# Проверка наличия записи в базе данных

Tags: php, база-данных

Как сделать проверку на email, если в бд не будет email чтоб писалось "в базе данных не найден email", а если бы был email в базе чтоб отправлялось восстановления пароля на email

Вот код, который проверяет:

```
elseif ($a=get_sql_row('profile',"rm='0' and name='email' and value='$id'")) {
    $error="в базе не найден e-mail";
    }
```

Ну он выводит "в базе не найден e-mail" когда email есть в бд, а когда нету email в базе то код отправляет восстановления пароля на email

Comment: помогите написать код верно

Comment: Может поменять знак = на == ?

Answer (score 3):

**По-уму:** продумать логику перед тем, как писать код. Например, как один из вариантов, если строить велосипед, то сделать в таком духе:

```
class UserInputException extends Exception { }
...
try {
    ...
    $profile = get_user_profile($id);
    if (!$profile) { throw new UserInputException("Пользователь не найден."); }

    $email = $profile->email;
    if (!$email) { throw new UserInputException("У пользователя не указан email."); }
    ...
} catch (UserInputException $e) {
    ... $e->getMessage(); ...
}
...
```

Или найти библиотеку/фреймворк, с готовой логикой для форм, чтобы только валидацию писать.

**По-индусски** (или просто по-ленивому, если код все равно скоро на помойку): сделать как-то так:

```
elseif (!($a=get_sql_row('profile',"rm='0' and name='email' and value='$id'"))) {
    $error="в базе не найден e-mail";
}
```

Если `$a` в boolean-контексте будет ложно, то условие выполнится. Если нет — в `$a` будет результат `get_sql_row()`, но `$error` установлен не будет.

Comment: у меня через class работать не будет в моем коде, и у меня не по ленивому написанно

Answer (score 2):

```
get_sql_row // это что такое?
```

Больше информации!

> get_sql_row значение которая проверяет
> строку в базе данных

а как-то по-русски написать? сам написал эту функцию? или нам звать наших экстрасенсов ?

ну а если по глупому то

```
and name='email' and value='$id'"
```

заменить на

```
and name='$email' and value='$id'" // или какая там у тебя переменная на мыло
```

Comment: and name='$email' and value='$id'" // тоже не работает, понимаешь у меня сам код
elseif ($a=get_sql_row('profile',"rm='0' and name='email' and value='$id'")) { $error="в базе не найден e-mail"; }
работает так если в бд есть мыло тогда пишет не найден, а если нету мыла то отправляет на почту), а мне надо сделать наоборот)

Comment: если значения в бд совпадают and name='email' and value='$id'

то код скажет что в бд есть email и не пропустит восстановления пароля, а как сделать наоборот, например есть в бд email то восстановления пароля прошло, нет email, восстановления не доступно

Answer (score 1):

Ну хоть до одного дошло...
У тебя было

```
elseif ($a=get_sql_row('profile',"rm='0' and name='email' and value='$id'")) {
    $error="в базе не найден e-mail";
}
```

то есть, если мыло в бд есть, то лови ошибку, так что знак логического отрицания (!), как уже сказал drdaeman, сделает логику верной

Comment: все заработало всем спасибо)))))